# How can I make my tex file (created in WinEdt) compatible with Scientific WorkPlace?

Tags: winedt

I have always used WinEdt as a LaTeX Editor and I love it. However, a colleague of mine uses Scientific WorkPlace, and apparently the `.tex` file created by WinEdt is not compatible with Scientific WorkPlace (it does not compile the file which in WinEdt is compiled with no errors). I had similar issues with another colleague who uses TeXnicCenter.

Does anyone know who can be done in order to fix these problems? How can I modify my `.tex` file (in WinEdt) in order to make sure that Scientific WorkPlace (or another LaTeX editor, such as TeXnicCenter) can effectively compile it with no errors?

Comment: Please include the errors you are receiving in your question.

Comment: Also: does Scientific Workplace files compile properly with WinEdt?

Comment: It finds thousands of errors... several of the packages that I use in WinEdt, also the simplest ones (like vmargin, subfigure and amssymb for example), do not work... There are messages saying: enter file name, eps file not found, amssymb not found...

Comment: Sometimes SWP compiles the file even with all these errors, some others it does not. Even when the file is compiled there are some problems, like figures (that it seemed not to find) overlapping the main text

Comment: Is it just a matter of fixing the preambles in both WinEdt and SWP in order to make the tex files compatible? If I remove some packages from my WinEdt original file, the situation seems to improve... but this is very annoying since this requires me to change many aspects of the file in order to obtain a similar result

Comment: Perhaps the SWP computer doesn't have a complete installation of TeX, and is therefore missing package. All just guess-work. We would need more information to diagnose the problem in a concrete fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good start would be to have your colleague export a file and to examine the SWP instructions which begin with a single `%`.  I've gotten it to work by (1) having my LaTeX file contain something like the following near the beginning

```
%TCIDATA{OutputFilter=latex2.dll}
%TCIDATA{Version=5.50.0.2953}
%TCIDATA{CSTFile=40 LaTeX Book.cst}
%TCIDATA{Created=Tuesday, February 11, 2014 19:14:32}
%TCIDATA{LastRevised=Tuesday, February 11, 2014 19:53:01}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="GraphicsSave" CONTENT="32">}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="SaveForMode" CONTENT="1">}
%TCIDATA{BibliographyScheme=Manual}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="DocumentShell" CONTENT="Standard LaTeX\Standard LaTeX Book">}
%BeginMSIPreambleData
\providecommand{\U}[1]{\protect\rule{.1in}{.1in}}
%EndMSIPreambleData
```

then (2) having the main file including other files as follows

```
%TCIMACRO{\QSubDoc{Include chap_pref}{\input{chap_pref.tex}}}%
%BeginExpansion
\input{chap_pref.tex}
%EndExpansion
```

and finally (3) assuring that the included files know what file is including them, such as

```
%TCIDATA{OutputFilter=latex2.dll}
%TCIDATA{Version=5.50.0.2953}
%TCIDATA{LaTeXparent=0,0,maintexfile.tex}
```

at the beginning.